# Query Elasticsearch from C# using webclient throws 400 bad request?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to call elasticsearch query  using webclient  in C#. My API url is correctly working with angular ajax call (POST) with passing some parameters and without.

The JSON I am sending in my query is:

```
{
    'from': 0,
    'size': 20,
    'sort': ['_score',
    {
        'publishDate': {
            'order': 'desc'
        }
    }],
    'query': {
        'bool': {
            'should': [{
                'query_string': {
                    'query': 'Test*'
                }
            },
            {
                'match_phrase': {
                    'reportName': 'Test'
                }
            },
            {
                'match': {
                    'researcher': 'Test'
                }
            }]
        }
    },
    'filter': {
        'bool': {
            'must': [{
                'numeric_range': {
                    'price': {
                        'lte': 99999
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                'numeric_range': {
                    'publishDate': {
                        'gte': '1957-06-25T07: 30: 27.806Z'
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                'numeric_range': {
                    'qualityScore': {
                        'gt': 0
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                'terms': {
                    'reportLanguageMaps': ['English']
                }
            }],
            'should': []
        }
    },
    'min_score': 0.005
}
```

This is my code:

```
var queryString = "{'from':0,'size':20,'sort':['_score',{'publishDate':{'order':'desc'}}],'query':{'bool':{'should':[{'query_string':{'query':'Test * '}},{'match_phrase':{'reportName':'Test'}},{'match':{'researcher':'Test'}}]}},'filter':{'bool':{'must':[{'numeric_range':{'price':{'lte':99999}}},{'numeric_range':{'publishDate':{'gte':'1957-06-25T07: 30:27.806Z'}}},{'numeric_range':{'qualityScore':{'gt':0}}},{'terms':{'reportLanguageMaps':['English']}}],'should':[]}},'min_score':0.005}";


WebClient testCLient = new WebClient();
var result = testCLient.UploadString(ESConstant.ESAPIConnection, "POST", queryString);
```

Now above code is giving me 400 bad request. If would not pass queryString it will success call and give me result (json , but without  apply filter is no meaning for me).

Comment: Your json appears invalid.

Comment: Its the exact same json i copied from header request on web page.(using chrome developer tools netwrok tab)

Comment: Ignore my previous comments, the linter did not like your `'` instead of `"`, this still could be your problem if your endpoint wants double quotes instead of single. I would also look into using `HttpClient` instead of `WebClient`, especially because you are dealing with a RESTful service.

Comment: You might also consider using the [Elasticsearch .NET Client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/introduction.html) for querying your index. This will allow you to build your query parameters in code as opposed to a string of text.

Comment: I  did try but its throwing me same 400 bad. I tried NEST.  well i will double check.

Comment: Well I tried simple one 

var  searchResponse = ESClient.Current.Search<EsModels.Report>(s => s.MatchAll());

Invalid NEST response built from a unsuccessful low level call on POST: /indexedkey/_search/indexedkey/report/_search
# Audit trail of this API call:
 - [1] BadResponse: Node: https://testelasticapi.com/indexedkey/_search/ Took: 00:00:01.4966069
# OriginalException: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.